OpenLayers 9 zooms in too far on feature extent
I am trying to zoom to the extent of a feature, but I cannot make it actually fit the feature completely within the map view. It always zooms in too far; what kind of math do I need to do to get it to actually fit? I'm in OpenLayers 9.
For context, selectedHUCs is an object like this {featureId: Feature} so I just get the first value (Feature) out of it.
const selectedFeatureExtent = Object.values(selectedHUCs).map((ft) => {
    return ft.getGeometry().getExtent()
})[0]

mapObj.getView().fit(selectedFeatureExtent, {
    size: mapObj.getSize(),
    duration: 1000,
})

I console.log(mapObj.getSize()) to make sure that it was reporting the same dimensions as the map container div and it is. I don't understand why OL won't respect the extent of my layer.
When I print out the feature extent, I get these coordinates:
[-12698330.63495976, 4975133.297025553, -10322056.299630199, 6275174.274099831]

When I print out mapObj.getView().calculateExtent(mapObj.getSize()) I get these coordinates:
[-16258259.1993944, 2844985.6519422685, -9138402.07052512, 7105280.942108838]

This is the starting view, where I'm attempting to zoom in on the purple feature:

This is the end view after zooming in:


If that is your feature extent the fit is working correctly https://i.sstatic.net/tCamxbKy.png so maybe you have the wrong feature?   Did you wait until the amination was complete before logging the map extent?

Thanks for pointing that out - after you asked if I had the right feature and some investigating, I realized because I am using a VectorTileLayer, the style is updating to look like it selected the whole feature but in reality it is only selecting the part of the feature that is on the tile I clicked on, thus the extent does not capture the entire feature and the zoom ends up zooming into the portion of the feature that was captured.
